# Codeigniter 2 migration running the latest version

Tags: php, codeigniter

In codeigniter2 i have the following migration file (1 to 8).

When running the method `$this->migration->latest()` i have observed the following:

1. While migration version is 0 (in migration table) , Only the first(1) migration and latest(8) will be executed and the migration version in the table will be updated to 8.
2. While migration version is greater >= 1, all migration file from 1 to 8 will be executed. The migration version in the table will be updated to 8.

Q : Is that normal? Or I am missing something here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats normal.

You may want to run migration per version like:

```
$this->migration->version(1);
$this->migration->version(2);
etc..
```

Running latest() will run all from current migration to the last.